# Component won't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to to create a component that display what is typed in an input field real time. I've seen it done using two components but I don't see why I couldn't do the same thing in one component.

The state is set in the constructor, I created a function that triggered by the onChange event and should trigger a function that calls this.setState to change the state to the new input but it does not seem to work.

You can see the code here:  https://codepen.io/AlexMercedCoder/pen/LYPbOXE?editors=0010

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: "Welcome!" };
  }

  changeTitle(e) {
    var title2 = e.target.value;
    this.setState(title2);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.title}</h1>
        <input onChange={this.changeTitle.bind(this)} />

      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from your `setState`function 
You should provide an object with the key of wich state property you wanna change

```
this.setState({myProperty : myValue})
```

your code must be like :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: "Welcome!" };
  }

  changeTitle(e) {
    var title2 = e.target.value;
    this.setState({title : title2});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.title}</h1>
        <input onChange={this.changeTitle.bind(this)} />

      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the state properly. You need to say what you are updating in the state:

```
this.setState({title: title2});
```

Comment: thank you, that works too, I also had another suggestion that is currently reflected in the wordpen where I just made the title2 variable const title and passed that to the setState function and that worked as well.

Comment: @AlexMerced Yes, that would work too. But you would still need to pass it in through an object, like so: `this.setState({title});`

Answer (score 1):

You need update your `setState()` statement to update `title` of the component's state and also make the `<input />` a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) by adding a `value` property to ensure the value in the input changes as you the user types:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: "Welcome!" };
  }

  changeTitle(e) {
    var title2 = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ title: title2 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.title}</h1>
        <input value={this.state.title} onChange={this.changeTitle.bind(this)} />

      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thank you, that works too, I also had another suggestion that is currently reflected in the wordpen where I just made the title2 variable const title and passed that to the setState function and that worked as well.

Comment: Great to hear. Even if you change the variable name to `title`, you still need to pass an object with `title` as a property like `{ title }`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do the following:

```
class App extends React.
  this.state = { title: "Welcome!" };

  changeTitle(e) {
    if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
      var title2 = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.title}</h1>
        <input onChange={this.changeTitle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Your problem was that you were trying to use `title2` as a shorthand property for the state but there's no `title2` in the state.